# Redirect to POST request after successfully processing another POST request

Tags: python, django

I have two independent POST requests which I'm trying to process one after another using Django. After first POST request, I'm trying to redirect to another view which is also a POST request and performs another functionality. When redirect happens, second view receives GET instead of POST request. I need to mention that requests represent two independent events and aren't connected but can be performed one after another. Does Django allow this kind of redirects or is there a way to trigger this behaviour?

Here's my code:

Template code that triggers first POST request:

```
<p>Are you sure you want to proceed?</p>
<form action="{% url 'participants-reset'%}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yes, match again.</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def participants_reset(request): #View that handles first POST request
    if request.method == "POST":
        Participants.objects.all().delete()
        messages.success(request, "Santa's list is empty again.")
        return redirect('match') #Attempt to trigger second POST request through url
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Woops. Something went wrong. Please try again.")
        return redirect('participants')

def match_pairs(request): #View that handles second POST request
    if request.method == "POST":
        #Another functionality
```

urls.py

```
    path('match-pairs/', views.match_pairs, name='match'),
    path('participants/', views.ParticipantsListView.as_view(), name='participants'),
    path('participants-reset/', views.participants_reset, name= 'participants-reset'),
```

**EDIT**

Thank you all for suggestions but unfortunately they didn't work. I managed to solve the problem by creating a template to which I redirected after first POST request and from which I triggered second POST request by button click. This will have to do until I figure out how to properly redirect requests.

Comment: You mean `redirect()` from `django.shortcuts` ? You can pass the arguments you need for the next function: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect .

Comment: Would it not be easier to just call the function directly tho? It's more efficient as you won't hit the server, wait for the request, etc...

Comment: Why can't you implement second post in the first one ?

Comment: @SyKer yes, it is `redirect()` from`django.shortcuts`. The next function needs literally no arguments from this function except to trigger the second event after this one is successful.  I trigger the same request through link and it works fine but this way it sends GET instead of POST. Can you please clarify your second comment? I don't quite understand what are you suggesting.

Comment: @Ahtisham I need to be able to access second post without first one. First one is just sort of a reset mechanism for the second event.

Comment: Just call the function directly with the `request` as argument. The POST data is in the `request`.

Comment: The answer you got is great but not efficient: you have to go through the whole: `prepare request >> send request >> wait for response >> process request` while the server (`nginx`, `unicorn` or whaterver) has to handle yet another request. All of that rather than just calling the function directly (`>> process request`).

Comment: It's a design choice: you can either "lock" the function with an import (it has to exist) or hit the webserver/load balancer more often. To be honest, neither are ideal.

Comment: @Sy Ker I tried your suggestion with calling the function. It either sends GET instead of POST or returns NoReverseMatch Error. Depending on the typing.

Comment: In `participant_reset(request)` you can't call `match_pairs(request)` directly? If yes, than do the same with you intermediary function.

Comment: And define the intermediary function with `intermediary(request=None)` So the other parts of the program won't through errors. After, return the `request` object if exists.

Comment: Sill doesn't work but thank you for your many suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use python requests module and call `requests.post` method with request body.
here is the document https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request

you can try something like below :-

```
def participants_reset(request): #View that handles first POST request
    if request.method == "POST":
        Participants.objects.all().delete()
        messages.success(request, "Santa's list is empty again.")
        r = requests.post(reverse('match'), data={'key': 'value'})
        return r #Attempt to trigger second POST request through url
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Woops. Something went wrong. Please try again.")
        return redirect('participants')
```

Comment: Tried this but now I'm getting MissingSchema Error with Invalid URL for match_pairs.